# React-native how to tab part of the screen

Tags: android, ios, react-native, tabs

I have some parts of the screen that stay permanent and one part of the screen which is a container that should change its content to one of a set of Card elements, according to a button press on a button group.

If I understand correctly I cannot use the Tab-Navigator (or the Stack-Navigator) because those control a full page (i.e. screen) change, and I only want to swap a single card element.

Am I correct about that?

If so what do I need to do? Is there some existing UI element for this? If nothing exists, how would I go about doing this?  Each card loads different stuff from a local json, and I don't want to reload them when switching back and forth...

I want it to have the effect shown in Android UI (non react-native) samples: [android Navigation Tabs in middle of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348816/android-navigation-tabs-in-middle-of-screen)

Perhaps I should be using swiper like in this answer?  [implement tabs in the center of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741372/implement-tabs-in-the-center-of-the-screen) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tab navigator, think about a structure like the one below

```
 <View>
     <OtherStuffThatFilLTheScreen>
     <TabNavigator>
     <OtherRandomStuff>
  <View>
```

Tab navigator will have full control of the element that renders inside its space, but will not change other elements outside its scope

Comment: So you are saying I was wrong in my assumption and that TabNavigator Can be used to be changed when buttons in buttonGroup are pressed. Could you show how this code should look?  I was about to post my own answer, where I just show and hide the other components, each one becoming the current "tab page"